# Simple Variable in Web Flow

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-webflow

I've different `view-state`'s in **flow.xml**. All of theses states have the same view. Now i want to set a variable which includes just a String und call it in the view-file to customize the content.
Here are my files:
**flow.xml**: *for the example two of the view-state's*

```
<view-state id="rcpm" view="rc/rcmembers.xhtml">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="RCHtmlCache.getCommunityList('rcpm')"
            result="flowScope.members" />
    </on-entry>
</view-state>

<view-state id="rcarch" view="rc/rcmembers.xhtml">
   <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="RCHtmlCache.getCommunityList('rcarch')"
            result="flowScope.members" />
    </on-entry>
</view-state>
```

In this file i need a variable with the value of the view-state ID, so e.g "rcarch".

**rcmembers.xhtml** *just the part of the code where i want to call the variable*

```
<p:panel id="panel" header="Memberslist of **Here comes the value of the variable">
```

Hope you understand my problem...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:

First, you can define it at flow definition level and expose it to the view directly:

```
<on-entry>
   <set name="flowScope.myView" value="flowRequestContext.currentState.id"/>
</on-entry>
```

Or you could pass the flow context to the controller and then expose it there:

```
<evaluate expression="RCHtmlCache.getCommunityList(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.members"/>
```

On the controller:

```
public String getCommunityList(RequestContext context) {
   context.getFlowScope().put("myView", context.getCurrentState().getId());
   ...
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: BIG THANKS! Your first option works absolutely perfect! Thanks a lot! I didn't know the command "flowRequestContext.currentState.id". Finally :) Thanks Again! Helps me a lot!

Comment: You are welcome :-) Just made a post about communication in Spring Web Flow 2. It may be useful for this case and others related: [blog](http://xpadro.blogspot.com.es/2013/04/communication-in-spring-webflow-2.html)

Answer (score 8):

Some users asked me after this question, how to set a simple variable with a String value. So the answer by **xpadro** helpds ME a lot, but some users click on this question to know how to set a simple variable with a string value. So I want to post here the answer also for that:
Use the code by **xpadro** and just replace the value with the string you want surrounded with `'` :

```
<set name="viewScope.variable" value="'String you want'" />
```

Like **xpadro** said, the `set` tag should stay inside the `on-entry`...
And to know which `Scope` you should use, take a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch03s05.html.

Hope i can help someone with that :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a subflow for this view-state?

This way you could have an input for you variable and call it from anywhere. No need to have multiple identical view states.

Comment: I have a scenario wherein, I need to jump from one flow to another sub-flow to and fro, I am doing that using `<subflow-state>`. My question is whether the variables defined using `<var>` of that particular flow gets instantiated everytime that flow is invoked or only once?

Comment: if the var is in the subflow, every time it is invoked